# Delta table Write Error - cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, delta-lake

I have an existing dataproc cluster with spark version 3.3 As per the doc https://docs.delta.io/latest/releases.html, Deltalake version 2.3 is compatible with spark 3.3. Hence followed below steps to install deltalake

- downloaded Deltalake jar to /usr/lib/spark/jars/

```
delta-core_2.12-2.3.0.jar
delta-storage-2.3.0.jar
```

- Added below entry in /etc/spark/conf/spark-deafults.conf

```
spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension 
spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog
```

**Trial-1: on Spark Shell on VM**

```
# connect to Pyspark
pyspark --packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.3.0 \
  --packages io.delta:delta-storage:2.3.0 \
  --conf "spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension" \
  --conf "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog"

# able to create dataframe and show()
>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>> history = spark.range(1,1000)
>> history = history.withColumn("type", lit("history"))
>> history.show()
# Errors out  
>> history.write.format("delta").saveAsTable("delta_sample_data_tab")
```

**Trial-2: Jupyter Notebook**

Config:

```
Kernel: /opt/conda/miniconda3/bin/python
Python version: 3.10.8 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Nov 22 2022, 08:23:14) [GCC 10.4.0]
PySpark version: 3.3.2
spark version: 3.3.0
```

Code:

```
>> import os
>> os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.3.0, io.delta:delta-storage:2.3.0 --conf spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension --conf spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog pyspark-shell'

>> spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('delta_session').getOrCreate()
# able to create dataframe and show()
>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>> history = spark.range(1,1000)
>> history = history.withColumn("type", lit("history"))
>> history.show()
# Errors out  
>> history.write.format("delta").saveAsTable("delta_sample_data_tab") # OR
>> history.write.format("delta").save("<hdfs_path>")
```

**Error on both Console and Notebook:** cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.f of type scala.Function1 in instance of org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF

```
23/08/08 16:33:43 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 4) (cluster-b6b8-w-1.c.test-382806.internal executor 2): java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.f of type scala.Function1 in instance of org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2076)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.checkObjectFieldValueTypes(ObjectStreamClass.java:2039)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkObjFieldValueTypes(ObjectStreamClass.java:1293)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultCheckFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:2512)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2419)
```